# 3D data handing in Python

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, dataframe, bigdata

I have 3D data (points with 3 dimensions) of ~2.2 million points which consumes 65 MB of memory for storage. Can anyone suggest me a Python library which is capable of handling and processing data of this size?

You can have a look at the sample of my data represented in the form of comma separated values which is shown below

337507.38, 3817723.32, 458.49

337507.94, 3817723.25, 458.16

337508.33, 3817723.26, 458.51

337508.83, 3817723.23, 458.43

337509.21, 3817723.24, 458.83

The values are of X, Y and Z axis which are separated by commas

Comment: numpy and Pandas for handling the data, mayavi for plotting

Comment: and [gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) for  exporting spatial data for later use

Comment: 22 millions times 3 coordinates times 4 (even just using floats with 4 bytes per value) is more than 260Mb, how did you get 65Mb?

Comment: @6502 I'm guessing either with compression or he's misrepresenting something

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try pandas  click : [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)